# MS SQL - HA & load balancing best solution for servers at different geo-location

Tags: load-balancing, sql, high-availability, failovercluster

Customers has App server (MS Server 2012) and Storage server (MS SQL 2012), with several hundred clients accessing server app via VPN.

Now they want to have a high-availability and also load balancing if possible, by setting up another same instance (App & Storage servers, 2012). But due some reasons the preferred location is another DC, and actual (measured) bandwidth availible to us is ~400mbps between these 2 sites (existing site and preferred one). As usual, the budget is also constrained :)

By digging, I found

**A)** "Peer-to-peer transactional replication" option, which as I understand, gives near-real time replication and also load balancing (but requires MS SQL Enterprise edition)

**B)**" AlwaysOn failover cluster instances" (WSFC) option (for 2 nodes, MS SQL Standard Edition is [OK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx#High_availability)). It is HA setup, but will not provide load-balancing.

The question is:

1. Is assumptions on A) & B) correct (HA, NLB)?
2. Is 400mbps bandwidth between 2 physical instances enough? It is assumed that daily SQL transactions/load is 5-10GB (SQL server network traffic).
3. I have very limited understanding on MS SQL and DB servers, so maybe other more optimal solutions? (but have to stick to MS SQL 2012)

Comment: `I have very limited understanding on MS SQL and DB servers` ... well, you're honest, that's nice... but if have very limited knowledge about MSSQL and databases in general, why are you trying to design a relative complicated MSSQL solution for a customer?  **Hire someone** who is knowledgable so that it gets done right.

Comment: This question is off-topic because designing a load balanced, high availability SQL environment across geographically separated instances is a *5-figures-professional-services* project, not a *solicit-free-advice-over-the-internet* project.

Comment: Well i didn't said I'M DESIGNING, it is just free help to estimate costs before deciding to "go" on "no go" with given budget..if it looks possible sure more professionals would be involved/hired...My impression is, it is not unique or complex setup. My DB experience is limited to MySQL/PgSQL etc for small webs (XAMPP) so no stuff like clustering, replication, administration etc